# Show external json data in html table

Tags: javascript, json

I get this error when im trying to display my json data in html it says undefined.
i thinks it's because it cant find my goods.varer and goods.pris and goods.billede. How can i solve it. Please help, its for an exam project.

this is my code

**varer.js**

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', async() => {
  let table = document.getElementById('varerTable');
  
  let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts", {method: 'GET', headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(console.log("error"));

  let tableHtml = `<tr>
  <th>varer</th>
  <th>pris</th>
  <th>billede</th>
  </tr>
  `;
  for(const goods in result){
    tableHtml += `
    <tr>
    <td>${goods.varer}</td>
    <td>${goods.pris}</td>
    <td><img src="${goods.billede}" style="height:50px;width:50px;"</td>
    </tr>
    `;

  }
  table.innerHTML = tableHtml;
});
```

**varer-controller.js**

```
router.delete("/delete:id", (req, res) => {
res.status(200).send(true);
```

});

```
router.get("/getproducts", (req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).json(products)
    console.log(products)
   })


//vis varer for en kategori
router.get("/getproductsforenkategori/:varer", (req, res)=>{
let category = req.params.varer;

if(products[category]){
  
  res.status(200).json({[category]:products[category]});
}
else{
  res.sendStatus(404)
}
});
```

**varer.json**

```
[{"varer":"ss","pris":"sss","billede":""},{"varer":"ss","pris":"sss","billede":""}]
```

**varer-controller.js**

```
router.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
    const varer = new varerModel(req.body.varer, req.body.pris, req.body.billede);
    vb.deleteGoods(varer);
    res.status(200).send(true);
  });

router.get("/getproducts", (req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).json(products)
    console.log(products)
   })
```

**Models**

```
class Goods {
    constructor(varer, pris, billede) {
      this.varer = varer;
      this.pris = pris;
      this.billede = billede;
    }
  }
  module.exports = Goods;
```

**dbvarer.js**

```
class VB {
    constructor() {
      this.salg = this.openFile(VARER_FILE);
    }
    /* CORE */
    // Save file
    saveFile(fileName, contentString) {
      fs.writeFileSync(ABSOLUTE_PATH + fileName, contentString);
    }
  
    // Open file
    //ændrer filename til userfile
    openFile(fileName) {
      const file = fs.readFileSync(ABSOLUTE_PATH + fileName);
      return JSON.parse(file);
    }
  
    /* LOGIN DB */
    saveGoods(varer) {
      this.salg.push(varer);
      this.saveFile(VARER_FILE, JSON.stringify(this.salg));
    }
    deleteGoods(varerne) {
        this.salg = this.salg.filter((x) => x.varer != varerne.varer);
        this.saveFile(VARER_FILE, JSON.stringify(this.salg));
      }
    
     
}
```

Comment: dear in the for loop console.log(goods) to see what properties it has

Comment: it gives me error and then 0 and 1??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing `async await` and `.then .catch`, I suggest you use only `async await` is more readable.

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const table = document.getElementById('varerTable');
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts", {
      method: 'GET', 
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    const json = await result.json()
    let tableHtml = `<tr>
    <th>varer</th>
    <th>pris</th>
    <th>billede</th>
    </tr>
    `;
    for (const goods of json){
      tableHtml += `
      <tr>
      <td>${goods.varer}</td>
      <td>${goods.pris}</td>
      <td><img src="${goods.billede}" style="height:50px;width:50px;"</td>
      </tr>
      `;
    }
    table.innerHTML = tableHtml;

  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Oh no ')
    console.error(err)
  }
});
```

EDIT

Some refactor:

```
async function getGoods() {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts")
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}

async function deleteGoods(id) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts/" + id, { 
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}

function renderTable(goods) {
    const table = document.getElementById('varerTable');
    let tableHtml = `
      <tr>
        <th>varer</th>
        <th>pris</th>
        <th>billede</th>
      </tr>`;
    for (const row of goods){
      tableHtml += `
        <tr>
          <td>${row.varer}</td>
          <td>${row.pris}</td>
          <td><img src="${row.billede}" style="height:50px;width:50px;"</td>
          <td><button onclick="handleDelete(${row.id})"> Delete </button></td>
          <td><button onclick="toDo"> Edit </button></td>
        </tr>
      `;
    }
    table.innerHTML = tableHtml;
}

async function handleDelete(id) {
  try {
    await deleteGoods(id)
    const goods = await getGoods()
    renderTable(goods)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }  
}

async function handleLoad() {
  try {
    const goods = await getGoods()
    renderTable(goods)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }  
} 

document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', handleLoad);
```

Comment: if i want to have a delete button beside each item, how should it be then. It could be so helpfull!!:)

Comment: You should add an id to each row `<tr id="${row.id}">...` and pass this id as param of the `onclick="handleDelete(${row.id})"` listner, then you can `findElementById` and delete it

Comment: Probably you want to send a DELETE request in `handleDelete`, if so... you can just call `getGoods` and `renderTable` after that

Comment: Can you accept my answer? 

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, i'm struggling a bit to get it implemented, could you maybe show how to implement it. Could help me so much with this exam! and again thank you!

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answare

Comment: But you have to implement the delete route in the server, are you using a database?

Comment: Give a look on this, it may help:

https://www.callicoder.com/node-js-express-mongodb-restful-crud-api-tutorial/

Comment: thank you!!! i've edited my code so it contains the delete route, and im just using json as my database

Comment: should i change the /delete route or the /getproducts in my varer-controller.js?

Comment: You should add a new one, with the param :id and the delete method

Comment: hmm i get this error when i run it varer.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: handleDelete is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (varer.html:1) and should the delete route be as in the edited code??

Answer (score 0):

If your result is an array, then you shoud use for...of loop, like this:

```
 for(const goods of result){...}
```